# How to generate signal with negative values?

Tags: matlab

I have to generate a discrete signal which is defined as:

```
1, -3<= n<=3
and 0 otherwise
```

Since matlab doesn't accept negative indexes of arrays how do I do it?
I imagined it was periodic and did this:

```
n=0:7;
x1 = [1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1];
```

Is this correct?
The problem is I have to make a **Fourier transform** after that.

Comment: Vectors such as your `x1` do not automatically bear an interpretation of their indices. You could think that `x1(1)` (the first element) corresponds to `n=-3` or whatever you want. You only need to _use_ `x1` according to your rule. You could even define an index vector such as `n=-3:6` to keep track of which time index corresponds to each `x1` sample

Comment: Matlab _does_ accept negative values, but not negative indexes of arrays.

Comment: @Igor: regarding your updated question. Is this a periodic signal or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use your x-vector's index as n-value, since that limits you to positive integers only. Create a separate n-vector with the corresponding n-values:

```
n = -10:10;
x = zeros(size(n));
x(n>=-3 & n<=3) = 1;
plot(n,x)
```

Or with smaller steps for n:

```
n = -10:0.1:10;
x = zeros(size(n));
x(n>=-3 & n<=3) = 1;
plot(n,x)
```

Comment: The OP is using standard signal-processing notation, where the horizontal axis is discrete time and is denoted as `n`, and signal values are commonly denoted as `x`

Answer (score 3):

Use a function handle:

```
y=@(n)(-3<n & n<=3)
```

And to plot it:

```
x=-7:7
stem(x,y(x))
```